# Facebook Graph API. Get public events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get public Facebook events with Graph API explorer. I can pull events with query like this `search?type=event&q=london`. Then I get 25 events, but if I go to next pagination page then I get empty data, because next link have parameter like this `&until=1422655200`

So why Facebook add random timestamp and maybe somehow I can set it by myself? Also how I could order data by start time and do not get past events?

Comment: Please include the full Graph API call you're making. 

I'm guessing you can add it as well. I would try setting  since=todays_timestamp&until=whenever_timestamp to your call.

Comment: I already tried it. Result is empty data array.